# Como o controller sabe que foi para ele sem eu passar o parâmetro no `echo open_form()`?

Tags: codeigniter

Eu tenho um codigo aqui que estou estudando como ele faz.
Veja essa view

```
insira o código aqui<div class="animate form login_form">
  <section class="login_content">

 <?php echo form_open('', 'id="form" name="form"'); ?>

 <h1>Login Administrativo</h1>
<div> <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'usuario_usuario', 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'usuario_usuario',     'placeholder' => 'Digite um Usuário')); ?> </div>
<div> <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'usuario_senha', 'type' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'usuario_senha',   'placeholder' => 'Digite uma Senha')); ?> </div> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Entrar </button>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="separator">
  <p class="change_link">Você quer criar uma conta?
 <?php echo anchor(base_url('admin#signup'), 'clique aqui!',    array('class' => 'to_register')); ?>
   </p>

  <div class="clearfix"></div><br />

  <div>
  <h4><i class=""></i> Luziânia Setor Leste GO</h4>
  <p>Igreja de Deus no Brasil em Luziânia</p>
  </div>

   </div>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>

  </section>
  </div>
```

essa view manda para o controller Login mais eu nao estou entendendo como ele manda esse formulario para o controller

Answer (score 1):

Quando não colocar o endereço para o processamento da página no servidor, o código se encarrega e coloca o endereço da página, no trecho de código logo abaixo, está bem claro isso:

```
// If no action is provided then set to the current url
if ( ! $action)
{
    $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
}
// If an action is not a full URL then turn it into one
elseif (strpos($action, '://') === FALSE)
{
    $action = $CI->config->site_url($action);
}
```

---

**Código completo:**

```
function form_open($action = '', $attributes = array(), $hidden = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // If no action is provided then set to the current url
    if ( ! $action)
    {
        $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
    // If an action is not a full URL then turn it into one
    elseif (strpos($action, '://') === FALSE)
    {
        $action = $CI->config->site_url($action);
    }

    $attributes = _attributes_to_string($attributes);

    if (stripos($attributes, 'method=') === FALSE)
    {
        $attributes .= ' method="post"';
    }

    if (stripos($attributes, 'accept-charset=') === FALSE)
    {
        $attributes .= ' accept-charset="'.strtolower(config_item('charset')).'"';
    }

    $form = '<form action="'.$action.'"'.$attributes.">\n";

    // Add CSRF field if enabled, but leave it out for GET requests and requests to external websites
    if ($CI->config->item('csrf_protection') === TRUE && strpos($action, $CI->config->base_url()) !== FALSE && ! stripos($form, 'method="get"'))
    {
        $hidden[$CI->security->get_csrf_token_name()] = $CI->security->get_csrf_hash();
    }

    if (is_array($hidden))
    {
        foreach ($hidden as $name => $value)
        {
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$name.'" value="'.html_escape($value).'" style="display:none;" />'."\n";
        }
    }

    return $form;
}
```